Factory-boy: use params in a factory.List field
I want to create a factory that will produce a list of dictionaries, and I want to be able to pass an iterable of items to serve as values for one of the items in those dicts, and I want the number of dicts in the list to be equal to the number of the items in the iterable I pass. Here's what I wrote:
class PostResponseFactory(factory.DictFactory):
    indices = (0, 10)
    errors = factory.List(
        [
            factory.SubFactory(PostResponseErrorFactory, index=x)
            for x in indices
        ]
    )

    class Meta:
        exclude = ["indices"]

    class Params:
        indices = (0, 1)

However, when I try calling the factory with the indices param, it has no effect (in fact, the Params are totally ignored).
PostResponseFactory(indices=[2, 4]) # still gives me indices 0 and 10

I tried using SelfAttribute in either the field or the for-loop, but I get the error that SelfAttribute is not iterable.
Is there a way to do what I want there?
